# GIT post-receive checkout without root folder

Tags: git

I'm new to git, trying to figure out how to have a website updated with each push by doing a checkout to the web root.
I have searched stackoverflow and only found topics about how to clone, which is not what i want.
So far i have set up my local and remote repos, and a post-receive hook:

```
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/path/to/website/httpdocs git checkout -f
```

My problem is that the project root folder is included in the checkout... when i push contents to the remote repo, i end up with something like

```
/path/to/website/httpdocs/project_root/index.php
```

What i would like to achieve is having

```
/path/to/website/httpdocs/index.php
```

How can I omit the project root folder while checking out?

Comment: it seems that the problem is caused by the eclipse git plugin (egit), which automatically creates a root folder with the name of the project. i now worked around it by changing the path to the webroot from `/path/to/website/httpdocs`to `/path/to/website/httpdocs/project_root`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If:

- /path/to/website/httpdocs is a git repo
- /path/to/project_root is a git repo (i.e. there is a `.git` directory)

Then you can use in your `post-receive` hook:

```
git --git-dir=/path/to/project_root/.git --work-tree=/path/to/website/httpdocs checkout -f
```

But if you are pushing to `project_root`, it is rather a *bare* repo, in which case, its root directory should be called `/project_root.git`, and the `post-receive` hook would look like:

```
git --git-dir=/path/to/project_root.git --work-tree=/path/to/website/httpdocs checkout -f
```

In any case, `project_root` must be the root of a git repo.

---

The [OP choppingblock](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1295865/choppingblock) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15927943/git-post-receive-checkout-without-root-folder/15930178#comment22764885_15927943):

> it seems that the problem is caused by the eclipse git plugin (EGit), which automatically creates a root folder with the name of the project.
>   I now worked around it by changing the path to the `webroot` from `/path/to/website/httpdocs` to `/path/to/website/httpdocs/project_root`.

Comment: the repo is in `path/to/website/git/myrepo.git`
i'm pushing to this from my local repo, but want to checkout to `path/to/website/httpdocs` (which is not a repo)

Comment: @choppingblock then the second post-receive hook I mention will do just that.

Comment: turns out the problem was elsewhere (see comment on the question).
since your answer was correct anyway, i set it to accepted.

Comment: @choppingblock ok. I have added your comment to the answer for more visibility.