# how to get the changed files from git for some particular tasks

Tags: git, deployment, amazon-ec2, web-deployment, pagoda-box

I am a php programmer and I am building an application.

I have a testing server(pagodabox) and a production server.(EC2).

After each task is completed I do a commit and push to testing server using git to test.
after several tasks are complete I want the changed files for all these tasks to be moved to my development server (EC2).

So how can I do this? Is there any way to move the changed files directly to production server?

Also is there any way to know the files changed for each task.

Both my testing server and production server has git installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is usually done is:

- you push on the testing server on a test branch
- when you are ready, you merge that test branch to master and push on the testing server on master.
- you have a post-receive hook which, on push on master branch, will push to the *bare* repo on prod (as illustrated in "[How to do branching approach for multiple sites?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16058559/6309)").
- you have a post receive hook on prod repo which will checkout the working tree in the live folder upon reception of the new commits. (as explained in "[git push origin master not pushing the files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22585742/6309)").

Comment: But the ec2 is not managed by me. can a second person pull the changes to ec2 ?

Comment: @RobinThomas sure, if that person has access to the prod server, he/she could pull from your test repo. But that same person could put in place the post-receive hook in that same ec2 bare repo, allowing you to push to test server, which in turn will push automatically on the prod ec2 server.