# Deploy GitLab repositories as a website on push served from the same machine that runs GitLab

Tags: git, web-deployment, gitlab

I have installed gitlab in my server. I am able to push code to several repositories. each repository is a website. I want to automatically update changes on each sites when I push respective repository in my gitlab.

Please note: everything is stored in the same server. Not use any extra cloud or servers. Only changes will be made and pushed from a local development computer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16077399/6309 should help

Comment: Use GitLab CI to deploy.