# git not recognizing remote repository

Tags: git, ssh, git-bash

This whole thing is because i want to have code deployed (and synced) to a live hosting enviromnet, for a website i'm working on (need to actually see the changes i'm doing) - the route being, `Bitbucket repo (code being worked on) -> local repo -> HostGator repo (results being visualized).`

I'm using `Git Bash` on Windows. I have a git repository on HostGator in `public_html` named "test" - configured and everything works fine - i can commit, branch etc.
They (HostGator) only allow for a `port 2222` on a SSH connection. I've created a local empty repository and then added the remote repository to the remote repository list, like so:

`git remote add localName ssh://username@address:2222/public_html/test`
This is because, try as i might, i can not get SSH to read and apply my local config file.

Then to test that everything works fine i've tried:

`git ls-remote ssh://username@address:2222/public_html/test`

This connects, asks for a password, and then fails with the message that `public_html/test is not a git repository`. I've checked permissions, everything's fine.

Question is: why does it fail and not recognize the repository? Is it something in my path, the way i add the remote repo?

**EDIT:** upon further investigations, even though the directory `test` is a repository and contains the .git folder, `git remote -v` shows the end path without the ".git" 'extension' - "public_html/test" as opposed to "public_html/test.git" , second being normal for a repository. This leads me to believe the syntax for adding it is not correct.

Comment: Is `public_html/test` a git repository?  It's not clear from your question that you've verified that.  Is there a `public_html/test/.git` directory in `username`'s home directory (or is `public_html/test` a bare repository)?

Comment: The folder `test` is, most definitely. `public_html/test` - a path, is not. That's why i'm asking if i'm adding the remote repository wrong. Perhaps git interprets the whole path as the name for the repository, in which case, the question becomes, how do i make it clear to git, i want to add as a remote repo, the `test` folder only - this is an assumption.

Comment: Git only operates on entire repositories.  The path you supply for the remote in `git remote add` must point to a directory that is either a bare repository, or a directory that contains a `.git` directory.  Relative paths (e.g., paths that do not start with `/`) are located inside the target user's home directory.  Does that clarify anything?

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not. The directory `test` is certainly a repository (and it contains the `.git` directory). The problem might be, that git interprets `public_html/test` as a whole name. In which case i'm still stuck on a syntax problem - but again, that's an assumption.

Comment: @larsks a little update, to not let things hanging. The guys at HostGator have no idea either, but i managed to circumvent my problem by not going through a local repository. Basically, ssh into my account and from there, `git init` a directory, clone an existing one from say, bitbucket and work with it as one normally would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The public_html folder in HostGator is in your HostGator account home directory. See "[`public_html` folder](http://support.hostgator.com/articles/cpanel/public_html-folder)":

[image: http://support.hostgator.com/img/articles/file-manager-home-directory.png]

Try and specify the full path:

```
git remote add localName ssh://username@address:2222/home/username/public_html/test
```

That being said, it would be best if:

- your repo was a bare repo in `/home/username/test.git`
- you had a post-receive hook which would checkout the content of the repo in `/home/public_html/test` (see "[GIT post-receive checkout without root folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15930178/6309)")

I mean, you can [push to a non-bare repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28381311/6309) (if the Git on the server is recent enough 2.3+), but the best practice remains a bare repo.

Comment: I have not checked since i found a workaround, but it would make sense that the issue is the path to my public_html folder. I'll mark this as accepted. Thank you.