# maintaining image files on server from database when pushing to the server

Tags: git

I have an images folder for a slider in my project that uses the database to create and serve the images. The problem I'm having is each time I push to the server I overwrite the files on the server and there a no images to display, how do I not delete the images on the server when pushing local project. I tried doing gitignore but that's no what I want because it will exclude the folder from being uploaded so I would have no path to upload to. I have also tried using git update-index --assume-unchanged public/data1/images/ and that doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 1):

One workaround would be to make sure the http configuration of your web server will serve images (url: http://yourServer/images/...) from a folder which is completely *outside* the tree where the bare git repo is checked out.

That way, on the production server, the git repo `images` folder is ignored.

Comment: I'm totally new to git and I don't understand what your saying could leave me some more explanantion and code please

Comment: @ONYX first, you should push to a bare repo that is then checked out somewhere. http://stackoverflow.com/a/15930178/6309. Or you can push directly to a non-bare repo: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28381311/6309

Comment: @ONYX Second, the rest is not git-related, but web-server-related: you need to configure your web-server in order for it to serve images coming from a folder which is *not* part of the checked out git repo.

Comment: @ONYX It depends on your actual web server. Here is an example for NGiNX: https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/serving-static-content/

Comment: @ONYX the main idea remains: no matter what you are pushing in the image folder of your git repo, it does not matter, because the web server will serve images coming from another completely different folder. No overwrite!

Comment: I really don't get this you need to explain the steps for me to get this - All I've been doing is adding and committing and pushing to the server that's all I know what to do, like I said I'm new to git. I have a local repo no repo on github or bitbucket - just pushing local to server at the moment

Comment: @ONYX As I said, the actual solution depends on the web server which runs on your local server. Is it Apache? NGiNX?

Comment: are you trying to make my repo on the server in a folder like /myproject/ and then have another folder on the server inside httpdocs /images/

Comment: I'm using fortrabbit so I don't actually no

Comment: @ONYX that is the idea: modify the web server config in order, just for the image folder, to be served from another folder: that way, you don't overwrite anything when you are pushing your git repo.

Comment: OK the web server config I don't know where that is! I'm using the website interface for set settings like ENV Vars etc and there is no webconfig.

Comment: @ONYX then that is a good question to ask to fortrabbit support: how to configure the server in order to serve images from another folder than the default one?